# ScaffoldMessenger throws a hero animation error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the new ScaffoldMessenger to show a snackbar if a user successfully creates a project.
While showing the snackbar, i navigate the app to the dashboard. But as soon as it hits the dashboard **There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree** error is thrown.
I am not using any Hero widget in my dashbard and I have one FloatingActionButton but its hero parameter is set to null.

**Sample code:**

```dart
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('A SnackBar has been shown.'),
          animation: null,
        ),
      );
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/dashboard');
```

Which results in this error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <SnackBar Hero tag - Text("A SnackBar has been shown.")>

Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <SnackBar Hero tag - Text("A SnackBar has been shown.")>

Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero
    tag: <SnackBar Hero tag - Text("A SnackBar has been shown.")>
    state: _HeroState#7589f
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero.<anonymous closure>
#1      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero
package:flutter/…/widgets/heroes.dart:277
#2      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor
package:flutter/…/widgets/heroes.dart:296
#3      ComponentElement.visitChildren
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4729
#4      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor
package:flutter/…/widgets/heroes.dart:309
...
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.
I suggest reading ScaffoldMessenger documentation: "When presenting a SnackBar during a transition, the SnackBar will complete a Hero animation, moving smoothly to the next page"

Comment: @Lucie I think the statement "When presenting a SnackBar during a transition, the SnackBar will complete a Hero animation, moving smoothly to the next page"
is what is causing the problem. Is there anyway the hero animation could be disabled?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. This happens if you have nested Scaffolds. The ScaffoldMessenger wants to send the Snackbar to all Scaffolds. To fix this you need to wrap your Scaffold with a ScaffoldMessenger. This ensures you that only one of your Scaffold receives the Snackbar.

```
ScaffoldMessenger(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: ..
    ),
)
```

Comment: It worked when i used only one parent Scaffold

Comment: This kinda defeats the purpose of having multiple Scaffolds in the first place

Comment: @DarkNeutron You can have multiple Scaffolds, but you should avoid nesting them. Check out the Nested Scaffold part of [Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html).

Answer (score 6):

I ran into same problem and fixed it by removing SnackBar before any call to `Navigator` with `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar()`.

Look like this with your **Sample code:**

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('A SnackBar has been shown.'),
          animation: null,
        ),
      );
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/dashboard');
```

Here's the link that helped me : https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger#migration-guide
Hope it'll work for you

Comment: Hi @GreenFrog Thanks for the answer. I am aware that you could remove the snackbar but to acheive this will require a lot of code. For instance, imagine if i want to handle the back button, I have to wrap my component with willpopscope and so on...

Comment: I think if we find a way to disable the hero animation (optionally) it would be better.

Comment: Any better solution than this? Facing the same problem and it's annoying what if I do want my snackbar to persist across page transitions

Comment: Getting error - ════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <SnackBar Hero tag - Text("Welcome Riya Ji!")>
Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero
    tag: <SnackBar Hero tag - Text("Welcome Riya Ji!")>
    state: _.....

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks If you haven't found an answer already, and this is still an issue for you, then try out my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by having the call run in the next event-loop iteration:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(), () => 
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(...)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, turns out I had a scaffold widget returning another scaffold in my subtree (whoops)

If so, then your snackbar is being popped on both scaffolds, and then initiating the transition causes the error.

Comment: But the doc says "When the ScaffoldMessenger has nested Scaffold descendants, the ScaffoldMessenger will only present a SnackBar to the root Scaffold of the subtree of Scaffolds. In order to show SnackBars in the inner, nested Scaffolds, set a new scope for your SnackBars by instantiating a new ScaffoldMessenger in between the levels of nesting."

Comment: Pretty sure that change was made recently.

Answer (score 1):

So this is clearly a bug in Flutter.

The best "official" workaround, is to show the snack bar on the next frame:

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   // ... show the culprit SnackBar here.
});
```

But we can all agree that it shouldn't happen in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @GreenFrog assumes that you're handling navigation on your own, in the case you're facing this problem while using the default back button behavior of the `Scaffold` widget you'll need to wrap your `Scaffold` in a `WillPopScope` widget, this basically vetos requests to `Navigator`, moreover by using `WillPopScope.onWillPop` you can essentially call `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();` just before the route is popped.

Example:

```dart
...
WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
      return true;
    },
    child: Scaffold(...,
  );
```

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for, I know you can use willpopscope to intercept but it will require a lot of code. I want to know the way to disable the hero animation that is causing the problem in the first place